# Como usar css em ion-list, ion-item?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo um app e nessa tela estou pegando dados de um json, então tenho que usar ng-repeat, só que desse modo não consigo usar os estilos css, pois ele não aceita div ou outro modo(pelo menos como eu tentei).

```
    <ion-list>  
        <ion-item>

           <a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'Name'"  href="#">
              <img ng-src="{{x.Image}}">
              <h2>{{x.Name}}</h2>
              <p>  {{x.Local}}</p>
            </a>

        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

O código sem json e com o css funcionando é esse:

```
<a class="item item-avatar" id="palestrantes" href="#">
  <img src="Fiona.jpg">
  <h2>Fiona Doohan</h2>
  <p> UDC, Dublin, Ireland </p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para usar css no Ionic você pode criar uma classe direto na ion-list, e controlar o estilo do componente, nesse caso pode evitar usar tags html e usar os componentes do framework.

```css
ion-list.custom ion-item {
  background: green;
}

ion-list.custom ion-label {
  background: red;
  color: #FFF;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<ion-list class="custom">
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>asddsd</ion-label>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```